# Which value of the apparent magnitude do I use from a Supernova light curve

Tags: telescope, distances, supernova, apparent-magnitude, light-curve

I am trying to get the distance modulus from a light curve of a supernova and obviously the apparent magnitude changes with time. Not only that but there are so many filters with different mags.

So my question is which mag value do I use from which filter and at what time? I have attached an example light curve I plotted of 2013aa supernova

Thank you very much :)

[image: Light Curve (Mag vs MJD) of SN2013aa]

Comment: Hint: A distance modulus requires an apparent and absolute magnitude, see e.g. [this](https://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/Carroll2/Carroll3_1.html) and the classic [Phillips 1993](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1993ApJ...413L.105P/abstract) paper on standardizable candles